# Can't run Python script in Visual Studio

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-2015, environment-variables, ptvs

I have installed Python Tools for Visual Studio 2015. Also I have Python 3.6 installed. The main propblem is that i can't even run simple script like:

```
print("Hello World")
```

I cant' even see error properly. The window closes too fast. The only thing i have recognized is "Error 21 invalid arguments" or something like this.

My Python Environment is:

**Prefix Path:**
C:\Users\Eugene\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32*

**Interpreter path**
C:\Users\Eugene\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe

**Windowed interpreter**
C:\Users\Eugene\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\pythonw.exe

**Language version**:
3.5

**Architecture**:
32-bit

**Path environment variable**:
PATH

On my computer PATH variable contains strings such as:
C:\Users\Eugene\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\;
C:\Users\Eugene\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\;

Comment: What happens if you run the script from the command line? The window won't close if you do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find an error. The problem was that i have created **IronPython** project not **Python**. Right now i have created Python project and everything works fine. By the way my Visual Studio recognizes Python directory.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2015 does not recognize Python 3.6
You can still use it but you have to explicitly  set the environment to the Python 3.6 each time you start Visual Studio.